# How to modify the existing object into new object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to implement the existing object `sampleobj` as shown in expected output.
I have key `jan, feb, mar,apr` and value seperated with commas, 
should take always first string as `begin` and second as `end`

"jan": "07:30,23:00" // begin,end

to

"jan_begin": "07:30",
   "jan_end": "23:00",

```
let res ={};
Object.keys(sampleobj).forEach(key => {
  Object.assign({},key_begin: sampleobj[key].split(",")[0], key_end: sampleobj[key].split(",")[1])
})
```

```
var sampleobj = {
  "jan": "07:30,23:00"
  "feb": "08:30,23:00"
  "mar": "07:30,22:00"
  "apr": ""
  "30-12-2019": "10:00,24:00",
  "31-12-2019": "11:00,24:00"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  month:{
   "jan_begin": "07:30",
   "jan_end": "23:00",  
   "feb_begin": "08:30",
   "feb_end": "23:00", 
   "mar_begin": "07:30",
   "mar_end": "22:00",    
   "apr": "",
  },
  fields: [
   {date: "30-12-2019", begin: "10:00", end: "24:00"},
   {date: "31-12-2019", begin: "11:00", end: "24:00"},
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the value first and then decide for an empty string or take splitted begin/end values.

```js
var object = { jan: "07:30,23:00", feb: "08:30,23:00", mar: "07:30,22:00", apr: "", "30-12-2019": "10:00,24:00", "31-12-2019": "11:00,24:00" },
    result = Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
            if (v === '') {
                r.month[k] = '';
                return r;
            }
            var [begin, end] = v.split(',');
            if (k.length === 3) {
                r.month[k + '_begin'] = begin;
                r.month[k + '_end'] = end;
            } else {
                r.fields.push({ date: k, begin, end });
            }
            return r;
        }, { month: {}, fields: [] });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```